# Why does my lighting not work?

Tags: lighting

A point-light in my scene won´t work. When I set it on sun-light the cube becomes white but the anvil stays completely black. Why might that be?

Here are the nodes from the highpoly mesh.
[image: highpoly]

And the Lowpoly version.
[image: lowpoly]

Comment: Hello. Can you [edit] your post to include a picture of the shader nodes for the anvil?

Comment: One thing to note is that the light power works very differently for sun lights than point lights, so if you have a 1000W point light and you change it to a sun, it will be a 1000 power sun, which will make everything completely white. generally the sun light uses values in the <10 range. not sure if this is your issue but it could be